# Create CMakeLists library with subdirectory sources

Tags: c++, cmake

```
project
 |
 |----- src  <-- Needs to be a library
 |       |
 |       |--- dir1 <-- Need not create a library
 |       |      |--- dir1_1.cpp
 |       |      |--- dir1_2.cpp
 |       |      |--- CMakeLists.txt
 |       |
 |       |
 |       | --- dir2 <-- has an executable for testing and needs to be a library
 |       |      |--- dir2.cpp
 |       |      |--- dir2.h
 |       |      |--- CMakeLists.txt
 |       |
 |       |
 |       | --- CMakeLists.txt 
 |
 |
 |
 |----- CMakeLists.txt
```

How do I create CMakeLists in `src` such that it includes files from `dir1` and `dir2`, such that only `dir2` is a sub-project. I want to use `add_subdirectory` in src/CMakeLists.txt to add source files from `dir1` and `dir2`. This way it will be easier to add more folders in the future.

I saw the use of `PARENT_SCOPE` but it also has some drawbacks. Is there a better solution? Maybe by using `target_sources` or something?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should reconsider not making those subdirs self-contained modules, as modularity helps keep your projects cleaned.

Having said that, you can include in any variable defined in `./src/CMakeLists.txt` any variable that's defined by `./src/dir1/CMakeLists.txt` or `./src/dir2/CMakeLists.txt`.  Here's an example:

Here are the contents of `./src/dir1/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
set(dir1_SOURCES 
    dir1/dir1_1.cpp 
    dir1/dir1_2.cpp 
)
```

Here are the contents of `./src/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
add_subdirectory(dir1)

set(src_SOURCES 
    ${dir1_SOURCES} 
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a library, then *later* add its source files in a subdirectory using [`target_sources`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.17/command/target_sources.html). This gives you the flexibility to add more sources to `MyLib` or add more sub-projects later on, via additional calls to `add_subdirectory`.

It might look something like this:

**src/CMakeLists.txt:**

```
# Create a library
add_library(MyLib SHARED)

# Traverse to the 'dir1' subdirectory to populate the sources for MyLib.
add_subdirectory(dir1)
# Traverse to 'dir2' to create a sub-project.
add_subdirectory(dir2)
```

**dir1/src/CMakeLists.txt:**

```
target_sources(MyLib PUBLIC
    dir1_1.cpp
    dir1_2.cpp
)
# Add any headers from this directory.
target_include_directories(MyLib PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
```

**dir2/src/CMakeLists.txt:**

```
project(MySubProject)

add_library(MyLib2 SHARED
    dir2.cpp
)
# Add any headers from this directory.
target_include_directories(MyLib2 PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})

add_executable(MyExe ...)

...
```